# Maximum perpendicular distance between two lines (not necessarily parallel)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Is there a general way to find the max perpendicular distance between two lines.
I have two lines $ a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1 =0  $ and $ a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2 =0  $

If I want to find the maximum distance between the two lines without placing any constraints on the coefficients, how would I do that

Attempt: I know I probably need to maximize the distance between the two lines, I'm just not sure how to get to the distance function.

Comment: What does this mean? Take the $x,y$ axes, what is the maximum perpendicular distance between them?